# Woocommerce missing plus minus buttons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce noob here. I've implemented a function to my woocommerce site to add plus and minus buttons to product quantities. This worked great when I only had 12 products but now i've loaded a lot more the products don't all load at once and when new products are added to the page the buttons are missing. Can anyone give me an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your functions.php file minimum value, maximum value and increment amount for products in woocommerce.

Default values are:

```
Quantity => 1

Minimum Value => 1

Maximum Vale => Any Quantity

Increment Amount => 1
```

We can change one to all of these values. To do this add the following lines of code at the end of your theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {

   $args['input_value']    = 1;         // Starting value

   $args['max_value']                      = 80;      // Maximum value

   $args['min_value']                       = 1;         // Minimum value

   $args['step']                   = 1;   // Quantity steps

   return $args;

}



// Variations

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {

                $args['max_qty'] = 80;                   // Maximum value (variations)

   $args['min_qty'] = 1;                   // Minimum value (variations)

   return $args;

}
```

Comment: Don't think this is what I meant

I mean that I've made plus and minus buttons to work next to my add to cart quantities. I have also enabled infinite scroll pagination so it loads the first 25 products and then another set of 25 and so on and so on. When the 2nd or 3rd set of products are loaded on screen the buttons are not loading with them.